# Prove that $\sin(x)+\cos (x)=\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

$$\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)=\sqrt2\left(\sin(x)\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)+\cos(x)\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)\right)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$$

Could you solve it from opposite? $$\sin(x)+\cos (x)=\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)$$

Second line is completely looking like magic to me. I was trying using Double angle formula. But, I couldn't relate it to anyone.

$$\sin (x)+\cos (x)=\sin (x)+\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}+x)$$

But, I know that

$$\sin (x+y) != \sin (x) +\sin (y)$$

$$\sin (48+30)=0.978147$$
$$\sin (48) +\sin (30)=1.243144825$$

So, they aren't equal. That's why I can't use formula of $$\sin (a+b)$$

Comment: Can you please tell what you have tried and where are you stuck

Comment: @JitendraSingh I have edited my question

Comment: The second line is the addition formula. Search $\sin(x+y)$.

Comment: $\sin(x+y)=\sin x \cos y + \cos x + \sin y$ Use this in second line rhs and get your lhs

Comment: Does the above answer your question Istiak

Comment: @JitendraSingh No I have edited my question again

Comment: Note also the value of $\sin \frac{\pi}4=\frac {\sqrt 2}2$...

Comment: $\sin (x+y) $ is not equal to $\sin x + \sin y$

Comment: @JitendraSingh Yes

Comment: The formula for the sine of an angle sum is $\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\sin b\cos a$.  Can you see how the first line works out with this?

Comment: Try multiplying and dividing the equation by $\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin x + \cos x&= \sqrt{2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \, \left( \sin x + \cos x \right) \\
&= \sqrt{2} \, \left( \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin x + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos x \right) \\
&= \sqrt{2} \big( \sin x \cos(\pi/4) + \sin(\pi/4) \cos x \big) \\
&= \sqrt{2} \sin(x + \pi/4)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Which formula did you use for the line $\sqrt2\left(\sin(x)\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)+\cos(x)\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)\right)$

Comment: @Istiak I didn't. Notice $\cos(\pi/4)=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $\sin(\pi/4)= 1/\sqrt{2}$, so I just replaced the $1/\sqrt{2}$'s from the previous line with those.

Comment: Sorry! $\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)$ How you find it?

Comment: @Istiak It's just the angle sum formula in reverse: $\sin A \cos B + \sin B \cos A= \sin (A+B)$.

Answer (score 1):

From
$$\tag1\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y$$
and
$$\tag2\sin(-y)=-\sin y $$
(both of which identities I assume as known and will not prove here), we obtain
$$\tag3\sin(x-y)=\sin x\cos y-\cos x\sin y$$
and by adding $(1)+(3)$,
$$\tag4\sin(x+y)+
\sin(x-y)=2\sin x\cos y. $$
Substitue $x+y\leftarrow u$ and $x-y\leftarrow v$, i.e., $x\leftarrow\frac{u+v}2$ and $y\leftarrow\frac{u-v}2$ to arrive at
$$ \sin u+\sin v=2\sin\frac{u+v}2\cos\frac{u-v}2$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the formula $\sin (x+y)$ as mentioned [here](https://www.math.miami.edu/%7Edscheib/teaching/spring12/mac1147_files/Trigonometric_Identities.pdf) .

See for first line we know $\cos\left(\dfrac\pi4\right)$ and $\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4\right)$ is equal to $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

So the expression reduces to $$\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)=\sqrt{2}(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{2}}) $$

Now I hope you can reduce it to second line.

For the second line use the formula I gave in starting of answer. Do tell if you can't solve yet in comment

Answer (score 0):

Note :

$$ a\sin(\theta)+ b\cos(\theta) = R\sin(\theta+\beta)$$

Using Double angle identity :

$$a\sin(\theta)+ b\cos(\theta) = \underbrace{R\cos(\beta)}_{\text{relates to a }}\sin(\theta)+ \underbrace{R\sin(\beta)}_{\text{relates to b}}\sin(\theta) $$

$$\tag{1} a \sin(\theta) = R\cos(\beta)\sin(\theta)$$
$$ a = R\cos(\beta)$$
$$ \tag{2}b \cos(\theta) = R\sin(\beta)\cos(\theta) $$

$$b = R\sin(\beta) $$
Then ,

$$ \tag{3}\frac{b}{a} = \frac{R\sin(\beta)}{R\cos(\beta)}=\tan(\beta)$$

Given that :
$$ 1\sin(\theta)+1\cos(\theta)$$

$$ ~a,b = 1 $$

Using Pythagorean theorem :

$$R = \sqrt{a^2 + b ^2}$$

$$R = \sqrt{1+1}= \sqrt{2}$$

$$ \tan(\beta) = 1 ; ~~\arctan(1) = \frac{\pi}{4} ; ~~ \beta = \frac{\pi}{4} $$

Thus,

$$R\sin(\theta + \beta) = \sqrt{2}\sin \left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{4} \right) $$